# Convert mysql Query to DB:: raw query

Tags: mysql, laravel

does anyone know, how to convert this query to raw querybuilder:

```
SELECT
    A.ID_KANWIL,
    COUNT(A.ID_CABANG) AS CABANG,
    SUM(JUMLAH_KARYAWAN) AS JMLKARYAWAN,
    COALESCE( B.JML_PESERTA, 0 ) AS JMLPESERTA 
FROM ORGANISASI A
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT 
            ID_KANWIL,
            SUM(JUMLAH_PESERTA) AS JML_PESERTA 
        FROM CAKUPAN 
        WHERE 
            BULAN=6 
            AND TAHUN=2017 
            AND ID_PROGRAM=1 
        GROUP BY 
            ID_KANWIL,
            ID_PROGRAM
    ) B ON A.ID_KANWIL=B.ID_KANWIL
WHERE 
    A.BULAN=6 
    AND A.TAHUN=2017 
GROUP BY 
    A.ID_KANWIL, 
    A.BULAN, 
    A.TAHUN
```

i had tried this,

```
$data=colletc(DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT
    A.ID_KANWIL,
    COUNT(A.ID_CABANG) AS CABANG,
    SUM(JUMLAH_KARYAWAN) AS JMLKARYAWAN,
    COALESCE( B.JML_PESERTA, 0 ) AS JMLPESERTA 
FROM ORGANISASI A
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT 
            ID_KANWIL,
            SUM(JUMLAH_PESERTA) AS JML_PESERTA 
        FROM CAKUPAN 
        WHERE 
            BULAN=6 
            AND TAHUN=2017 
            AND ID_PROGRAM=1 
        GROUP BY 
            ID_KANWIL,
            ID_PROGRAM
    ) B ON A.ID_KANWIL=B.ID_KANWIL
WHERE 
    A.BULAN=6 
    AND A.TAHUN=2017 
GROUP BY 
    A.ID_KANWIL, 
    A.BULAN, 
    A.TAHUN") ))->get()
```

but i got error

```
Call to a member function get() on array
```

Answer (score 0):

you use the `->get()` on the "`colletc`" function

remove the ->get() it should work

i suggest you to use the model relations and you dont need to make querys like you do

Comment: thanks @peter, i have replace ->get() with all(), thats work perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$data = DB::select(
  "
  SELECT A.ID_KANWIL,
        COUNT(A.ID_CABANG) AS CABANG,
        SUM(JUMLAH_KARYAWAN) AS JMLKARYAWAN,
        COALESCE(B.JML_PESERTA, 0) AS JMLPESERTA
  FROM ORGANISASI A
  LEFT JOIN
    (
     SELECT ID_KANWIL,
            SUM(JUMLAH_PESERTA) AS JML_PESERTA
     FROM CAKUPAN
     WHERE BULAN = :param1
       AND TAHUN = :param2
       AND ID_PROGRAM = 1
     GROUP BY ID_KANWIL,
              ID_PROGRAM
    ) B
    ON A.ID_KANWIL = B.ID_KANWIL
  WHERE A.BULAN = :param3
    AND A.TAHUN = :param4
  GROUP BY A.ID_KANWIL, A.BULAN, A.TAHUN
  ",
  [
    "param1" => $bulan,
    "param2" => $tahun,
    "param3" => $bulan,
    "param4" => $tahun,
]);
```

This query is build using **Named Bindings**. You can read more about it [here](https://laravel.com/docs/master/database#running-queries)

In the query, word `:param1` will be replaced with value of `$bulan`

`:param2` replaced with `$tahun`...

`:param1` in the query needs to match key of the array provided as second argument to `DB::select()` (which in this case is `"param1" => $bulan,`)

One thing you need to know is if you want to use same `$bulan` variable again, you need to add new one with `:param3` that will get the value of `"bulan3" => $bulan,`

Comment: thank you verru much, i got error, .. and i give DB::Raw( befor db::select). and work fine

Comment: be careful when you use `DB::raw()` especially if you are passing variables (example `$bulan`) inside the query. That could leave you open to [sql injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection). That's why I provided you with solution that uses **Named Bindings**